# Pass javascript variables into a {% static "..." %} pathway text

Tags: javascript, python, django

I am trying to create the following array for my server, which serves to preloading the images with given paths:

```
var i = 0;
while (face_cursor < faces_gone_through.length) {
    for(j=0; j<=100; j+=10) {
        load_images_array.push('{% static "/img/' +
faces_gone_through[face_cursor] + '/' + faces_gone_through[face_cursor+1] +
'/' + faces_gone_through[face_cursor] + '_' + j + 'P_' +
faces_gone_through[face_cursor+1] + '.jpg" %}');
    }
    i++;
    face_cursor+=3;
}
face_cursor=1;
```

The code may seem weird, but what i am basically doing is trying to concatenate the given strings and try to create an array of paths. But the concatenation doesn't work and the string is parsed as:

```
/static/img/&#x27;%20%2B%20faces_gone_through%5Bface_cursor%5D%20%2B%20&#x27;/&#x27;%20%2B%20faces_gone_through%5Bface_cursor%2B1%5D%20%2B%20&#x27;/&#x27;%20%2B%20faces_gone_through%5Bface_cursor%5D%20%2B%20&#x27;_&#x27;%20%2B%20j%20%2B%20&#x27;P_&#x27;%20%2B%20faces_gone_through%5Bface_cursor%2B1%5D%20%2B%20&#x27;.jpg
```

How can one successfully concatenate this string?

Comment: You're mixing server side tags with a front end language, you won't be able to use any javascript with the django `static` tag, either construct the array in the view or with django template language if you can

Answer (score 0):

Assembling strings has become easier with ES6. The easier way to create and fill such strings is with Template literals. Enclosed is the link to the MDN page [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

```
`string text ${expression} string text`
```

Comment: Sadly, this doesnt work either. The string `{% static "/img/${faces_gone_through[face_cursor]}/${faces_gone_through[face_cursor+1]}/${faces_gone_through[face_cursor]}_${j}P_${faces_gone_through[face_cursor+1]}.jpg" %}` is then parsed as `static/img/&#x27;%20%2B%20faces_gone_through%5Bface_cursor%5D%20%2B%20&#x27;/&#x27;%20%2B%20faces_gone_through%5Bface_cursor%2B1%5D%20%2B%20&#x27;/&#x27;%20%2B%20faces_gone_through%5Bface_cursor%5D%20%2B%20&#x27;_&#x27;%20%2B%20j%20%2B%20&#x27;P_&#x27;%20%2B%20faces_gone_through%5Bface_cursor%2B1%5D%20%2B%20&#x27;.jpg`